# How to group icons based on category on the desktop?

Tags: icons, customization

I have a lot icons on the desktop and I want to manage them by grouping icons of related programs. However, I haven't found any utility like fences in Windows.

Have you met any utility like that yet?

Comment: Do you know how to configure the program [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any such utility for Unity or Gnome based desktop yet. But KDE4 has this feature.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

[Go to this page](http://www.kde.org/screenshots/) for more screenshot. You can use that applet to categorize icons on desktop.